# agregar alias en select count(*) anidado

Tags: mysql

tengo la siguiente consulta SQL:

```
select count(*) from
(
SELECT count(*) 
FROM income 
where empresa=2 
and month(fecha) =1 
and year(fecha) = 2021 
and active = 1 
group by entidad) as numrows
```

el gestor no me toma el alias numrows, ¿cómo podría definirlo para tomarlo después desde php?

Comment: @Excorpion por qué?

Comment: @Excorpion es una consulta anidada, al agrupar por entidad da dos filas y quiero contar esas con el select externo.

Answer (score 0):

Tengo dudas de si tu ejemplo realmente funciona, pero si quieres utilizar sub consultas la estructura seria la siguiente

```
SELECT
    count(*) as publicaciones_count,
    (select count(*) from comentarios_de_publicaciones) as comentarios_count,
FROM
    publicaciones
```

La sub consulta nos entregará un valor único, que se encapsulará bajo su alias asignado en la consulta original `comentarios_count`. Ahora hay un pequeño detalle, la sub consulta siempre entregará el contador de comentarios general con el mismo valor para todas las tuplas...

Puedes mezclar las columnas (de forma contextual) de la consulta original con la sub consulta, asignando identificadores de tablas, veamos un ejemplo.

```
SELECT
    count(*) as publicaciones_count,
    (select count(*) from comentarios_de_publicaciones cp where cp.publicacion_id = p.id) as comentarios_count,
FROM
    publicaciones p
```

En el ultimo caso, la subconsulta obtendrá su valor de forma contextual, por lo cual, esta sub consulta entregará el contador de comentarios para cada publicación.

Comment: si utilizo la primera me da un error porque  la sub consulta arroja más de dos filas y esas son las que quiero contar, la consulta que puse funciona, pero el problema es el alias que no lo toma.

Comment: No te lo toma porque están después del ````from````, estás reemplazando el nombre de las tablas por la consulta, los alias sirven para las columnas, por eso debes realizar la sub consulta antes del from, como te indico en la publicación, reestructurando tu consulta

Comment: la consulta con el group by retorna más de una fila(error) al usar tu estructura, cómo puedo contarlas con su alias correspondiente?

Comment: con esta consulta funciono select count(*) as numrows from
(
SELECT count(*) 
FROM income 
where empresa=2 
and month(fecha) =1 
and year(fecha) = 2021 
and active = 1 
group by entidad) as numrows